# non static method calls without creating an object inside onCreate()

Tags: java, android, oop, static, oncreate

I heard that in java Instance (non-static) methods work on objects and to invoke non static method requires to have a reference to an instance.
But here in this Java(Android) code non Static method is called without creating an object inside onCreate() method and no errors. I wonder why is that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    newGame();


}


private void newGame(){

    // code here

}

}
```

sorry for my low knowledge in java

Comment: Activities are instantiated by the system. So when you're inside the `onCreate()` method, an instance of your Activity has already been created. The call to `newGame()` can also be written as `this.newGame()`, where `this` refers to the current instance of the class you're in. `this` is oftentimes omitted unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the method newGame() is the member method of your class/activity name MainActivity. According to OOP concepts, you don't need class object if you are calling member method of same class. It is same like member variable. That is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an instance. Java objects are created with a constructor, since your `MainActivity` didn't include one you got a default one. It looks like,

```
public MainActivity() {
  super();
}
```

Then your `onCreate()` is invoked on that instance.